# Grails - How to embed wiki pages into a Grails application

Tags: grails, wiki, moinmoin, xwiki, tiki-wiki

I am wiling to have some pages of my application use a wiki based technology such as XWiki, MoinMoin, Tiki Wiki, ...
My main concern is not having to re-code the "edit", "preview", "history comparator" features.

How could I do that? Would iframes be a solution? Has someone already done that?

Any suggestion is most welcome.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems grails.org has its own wiki implementation. You can see it in action if you register at grails.org and for instance go to [Success Stories](http://grails.org/Success+Stories) where you have the links Edit and View Info.

You can find the source code for the implementation [here](https://github.com/grails-samples/grails-website).

Comment: Thank you very much ! I never used it so I did not even know about it. Would you know of any way to easily extract the wiki part of the application, or I have to do it all manually, digging through the source code ?

Comment: I haven't used it either, but I had a look at the source code and it seemed quite easy to grasp. Good luck & glad I could help!